# Can writing to a UDP socket ever block?

Tags: python, udp, twisted, statsd

And if so, under what conditions? Or, phrased alternately, is it safe to run this code inside of twisted:

```
class StatsdClient(AbstractStatsdClient):
  def __init__(self, host, port):
    super(StatsdClient, self).__init__()
    self.addr = (host, port)
    self.server_hostname = socket.gethostname()
    self.udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

  def incr(self, stat, amount=1):
    data = {"%s|c" % stat: amount}
    self._send(data)

  def _send(self, data):
    for stat, value in data.iteritems():
      self.udp_sock.sendto("servers.%s.%s:%s" % (self.server_hostname, stat, value), self.addr)
```

Comment: I believe it is blocking by default and you have to use `self.udp_sock.setblocking(0)` to set it to nonblocking, in which case it will raise an exception if it cannot send the data immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, oddly, a UDP socket can block.

The conditions under which this can happen are basically, some buffers somewhere fill up, your operating system decides it's time for something to block.  These are arguably kernel bugs, but I've seen them here and there.  You can definitely get `EWOULDBLOCK` sometimes under obscure, impossible-to-reproduce conditions.

Why would you want to do this in Twisted instead of using Twisted's [built-in UDP support](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html) though?

Comment: Also, Python-specifically, if "host" needs to be resolved, then Python will happily do that resolution for you, blockingly, regardless of the state of the UDP socket.

Comment: Oh yea, and sort of related-ish, I guess, `socket.gethostname` can block too!

Answer (score -1):

It could fail if your network interface goes down, for example:

[ENETDOWN]         The local network interface used to reach the destination is down.

Comment: That's a failure condition, not a blocking condition.